# Using C++ std::filesystem to validate a directory

Tags: c++, std-filesystem

For the C++ function `std::filesystem::is_directory(path)`, what is the definition of "is a directory"?

For example with `std::filesystem::path = p(".\\xyz")`, `is_directory(p)` returns `false`. The directory `xyz` does not exist, but the path functions just inspect the path, not the files on disk.

In my situation, user is inputting a string, and I need to check that it is a valid path for the Windows NTFS filesystem, then that it is a valid directory name (under Windows, if it's a valid path it should be a valid directory name), then that the directory already exists. If any of these is not true, then I need to give the user an error message explaining what is wrong.

Windows 11, Visual Studio 2022

**Update 1:** I want to do my checking using only `std::filesystem`, not Boost or Microsoft-specific functions. All the cited "duplicates" use functionality outside `std::filesystem`.

**Update 2:** I was able to accomplish what I wanted by using the `fs::is_directory(fsp, ec)` form and checking the error code `ec`.

Comment: It is not just parsing a path to determine this.  It uses the actual underlying filesystem to test the status and verify that the directory path you give it and is a directory.  So it must already exist on disk

Comment: `std::filesystem::path`'s methods are just string manipulations, the functions in the `std::filesystem` namespace itself do interact with the disk

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. So I guess using `std::filesystem`, you cannot determine only whether the path is valid for Windows. This distinction is needed to report the error to the user.

Comment: @Woody20 `std::filesystem::status(p).type() == std::filesystem::file_type::directory` will be `true` if `p` is a directory

Comment: @TedLyngmo is that not just a long winded version of `std::filesystem::is_directory(p)`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, exactly, but I got the impression OPs `is_directory`  was broken somehow. Perhaps I'm reading too much into what OP says - and if `is_directory` is broken, `status` probably is too.

Comment: No, `is_directory` is not broken for the OP.  He just wants to be able tell if a string of characters *would* make a valid directory name, not if it exists on disk.